# How to separate DPR:3 mobile from DPR:3 monitor @media

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to use @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) only for mobile, but not for desktop devices. How do I seperate them ?

Comment: By device detection, which is really not the best way to go, as there is not a reliable way to do it. Why do you need that?

Comment: Also, it is not recommended to use `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` in production: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio

Comment: What about min/max-width/height?

Comment: @LGSon hey. I want to make mobile version for all mobile devices, for the ones with 1200px and DRP:3 too. Now if visitor comes to website with monitor DPR:3 he also sees mobile version